# Не могу решить проблему [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, администрирование, kernel

*Добрый день*

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
```

**Эта проблема уже больше 2ох месяцев ......**

(Ноут +syslog) много ошибок такого плана но работает нормально вроде как . 
....

```
Product Name: Inspiron 15-3573
```

-

```
kernel: [ 5531.010580] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=332887 end=332888) time 2158 us, min 763, max 767, scanline start 713, end 16
```

-

```
[drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=106733 end=106734) time 1633 us, min 763, max 767, scanline start 728, end 6
```

-

```
 *-display                 
   описание: VGA compatible controller
   продукт: Intel Corporation
   производитель: Intel Corporation
   физический ID: 2
   сведения о шине: pci@0000:00:02.0
   версия: 03
   разрядность: 64 bits
   частота: 33MHz
   возможности: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   конфигурация: driver=i915 latency=0
   ресурсы: IRQ:126 память:81000000-81ffffff память:90000000-9fffffff ioport:f000(размер=64) память:c0000-dffff
```

- Побывал изменить параметр на 1 (Не помогло )

  ```
  echo 1 > /sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_psr
  ```

Есть варианты ?

Comment: Всегда начинайте с использования последнего ядра (на сегодня v5.7). Этот драйвер -- одна из самых горячих тем в каждой версии ядра.

Answer (score 0):

`Обновить ядро ++++` -

> 5.4.0-53-generic